# Run NodeJS server through SSH without hanging from disconnect

Tags: linux, node-js, ssh

I have a NodeJS server on a virtual machine. I connect to the machine through SSH and leave the server running with:

```
npm start &
```

If I disconnect with `Ctl-D`, the server keeps running. If my internet drops and the connection fails, the server also stops. Why does this happen, and how can I leave the server running without it dropping because of the internet disconnection?

Answer (score 1):

Even when it is running in the background, the server is still a child process of your ssh session.   To get it to run independently, you can run it with [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup):

```
nohup npm start &
```

Wikipedia says:

> Note that nohupping backgrounded jobs is typically used to avoid terminating them when logging off from a remote SSH session. A different issue that often arises in this situation is that ssh is refusing to log off ("hangs"), since it refuses to lose any data from/to the background job(s). This problem can also be overcome by redirecting all three I/O streams:

```
nohup npm start > npm.out 2> npm.err < /dev/null &
```

Comment: I ran `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=50000 NODE_ENV=production nohup npm start  >> stdout5.md 2>> stderr5.md < /dev/null &`, the SSH session disconnected because of an internet failure, and the server went down. How can I debug it?

Comment: Can you close the ssh session manual (ctrl-d) just after starting the server and have it stay up?

Comment: You could also try configuring npm as a system service: https://serverfault.com/questions/1018676/how-to-configure-systemd-service-unit-to-start-node-app-with-npm-start-instead

Comment: Yes, if I disconnect the session manually, then the server stays up, with or without `nohup`. The problem is if I forget to disconnect or am running other commands.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would help, but I usually configure my SSH client to detect timeouts and reconnect: `$ cat ~/.ssh/config 
ConnectTimeout 10
ConnectionAttempts 100`  you could also try using a keep alive ping with `ServerAliveInterval 60`.   Those might reduce the problem.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that you still have this problem when using `nohup`.   If that isn't working for you, my only other suggestion is configuring npm as a service.

Comment: The SSH session drops every time my ISP changes my IP address. I got into the habit of disconnecting when I restart the server, but sometimes I forget and sometimes it stops in the middle of running other commands, and I was looking for a surefire way to avoid it. Thanks anyway!